# NIST example shows extra hexadecimal characters in Block Contents of SHA512-256

Tags: hash, nist, sha-2

I was recently trying to gain a better understanding of the [SHA-512/256 algorithm](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-107r1.pdf) and on [this NIST example](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA512_256.pdf) they use the word "abc" as the input. In the Block Contents, it shows the expected hexadecimal `616263` (abc), although why is it directly followed by `0x80` and `0x18` at the very end?

```
Block Contents:
W[ 0] = 6162638000000000
W[ 1] = 0000000000000000
W[ 2] = 0000000000000000
W[ 3] = 0000000000000000
W[ 4] = 0000000000000000
W[ 5] = 0000000000000000
W[ 6] = 0000000000000000
W[ 7] = 0000000000000000
W[ 8] = 0000000000000000
W[ 9] = 0000000000000000
W[10] = 0000000000000000
W[11] = 0000000000000000
W[12] = 0000000000000000
W[13] = 0000000000000000
W[14] = 0000000000000000
W[15] = 0000000000000018
```

I realize the zeros are padding, however, it's the `0x80` and `0x18` presence I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the byte padding of SHA-512 encoded as the big-endian, simply

- add bit `1`, that is the last `0x80` in the begging part
- fill zeros
- then add the size in the 128-bit big-endian in the end. 0x18 is 24 bytes which are for the 3 characters.

---

- More formal;

[NIST FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) on page 13 defines the padding scheme for SHA-512 as;

> Suppose that the length of the message, $M$, is $\ell$
> bits.  Append the bit `1` to the end of the message, followed by $k$ zero bits, where $k$ is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation
> $$\ell + 1 + k \equiv  896 \bmod 1024$$

---

- Your case that fits one block.

Your message size is $\ell =24$ than

$$24 + 1 + k \equiv  896 \bmod 1024$$ solving for minimal $k = 896-24-1 = 871$. Therefore the padded message is

$$ \text{padded message } = \overbrace{M}^{24-bit} \mathbin\| \overbrace{1}^{1-bit} \mathbin\| \overbrace{000\cdots 000}^{871-bit\; 0s} \mathbin\| \overbrace{00000000\cdots00011000}^{128-\text{bit binary encoded length } \ell} $$